# Jquery and loading json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json that is produced by an app and dumped into the current folder (app.json)

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "2": "Mdss"
        },
        {
            "3": "MdssWeb"
        },
        {
            "4": "Coherence"
        },
        {
            "5": "TradeEngine"
        },
        {
            "6": "MdcManager"
        },
        {
            "7": "Mdc"
        },
        {
            "8": "Omds"
        },
        {
            "9": "payments-core"
        },
        {
            "10": "cashier"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I read in into Jquery to populate a  field in a html page

Comment: what you have tried, this could be very simple?

Comment: A lot of jquery functions, none had any effects to my shame.

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? Show us your effort!

Comment: Use `$.getJSON`, then loop over the response and populate your fields.

Comment: That data is really poor. Why does each object have a different key?

Comment: $.getJSON("app.json", function(data){
           $.each(data.app, function(){
        // how do I access the fields here?      
    });

Comment: Can you fix the app so it just returns an array of strings, instead of those confusing objects?

Comment: Because they are different apps

Comment: Little tricky Groovy app

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.apps, function() { // Iterate over the `apps` array
    $.each(this, function(appNumber, appName) { // Iterate over the properties in each object
        // Do stuff with appNumber and appName
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rf1q8cev/1/)

Comment: $("#btApplist").click(function(){
              $.getJSON('H:\\STATUSALL\\app.json', function(data){
                     $.each(data.apps, function() {
                         $.each(this, function(appNumber, appName) {
                             $('#apps').empty().append(new Option(appName, appNumber));
                         }
                     }    
              }
          });

Still have problems.

Comment: You're emptying `$("#apps")` each time through the loop. You should empty it before the loop, and then append to it inside the loop.

Comment: $("#btApplist").click(function(){
       
     $.getJSON('H:\\STATUSALL\\app.json', function(data){ 
               $.each(data.apps, function() { 
                   $.each(this, function(appNumber, appName) { 
                       $('#apps').append(new Option(appName, appNumber)); 
                   } 
               }
           }
     
      });
Still not working... I wonder why...

Comment: Is it doing anything? Have you tried setting breakpoints to see what's in `appNumber` and `appName`

Comment: I doesen't do anything and also block my other click events.

Comment: I was missing a `{` on the first line. Didn't you notice the syntax error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myJson = {
    "apps": [
        {
            "2": "Mdss"
        },
        {
            "3": "MdssWeb"
        },
        {
            "4": "Coherence"
        },
        {
            "5": "TradeEngine"
        },
        {
            "6": "MdcManager"
        },
        {
            "7": "Mdc"
        },
        {
            "8": "Omds"
        },
        {
            "9": "payments-core"
        },
        {
            "10": "cashier"
        }
    ]
};
var myJson = {
    "apps": [
        {
            "2": "Mdss"
        },
        {
            "3": "MdssWeb"
        },
        {
            "4": "Coherence"
        },
        {
            "5": "TradeEngine"
        },
        {
            "6": "MdcManager"
        },
        {
            "7": "Mdc"
        },
        {
            "8": "Omds"
        },
        {
            "9": "payments-core"
        },
        {
            "10": "cashier"
        }
    ]
};

for(var i in myJson.apps){
  for(var x in myJson.apps[i]){
    // myJson.apps[i][x]; // is your value
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to load it from a file but it may work.

Comment: sure it will. you have only to assign file contents to the variable.